# Python 3 Typeerror

Tags: python, random, typeerror

I'm writing a program which will simulate shooting at a target. I have run into a problem. I get the error `"TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"`.

The code:

```
import random
import math
def present(l):
        i=0
        while i<=10:
                for x in range(i,4+i):
                        print(l[x]+"/",end="")
                i=i+5
                print("\n")
def xypoang(x,y):
    langd=math.sqrt(x*x+y*y)
    poang=(110-langd)/20
    if poang>110:
        poang=0
    poang=round(poang)
    return poang

def userwant(randomlist,person):  #person is number of person
    personind=int(person)*5
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    list3=[]
    for r in range(1,11):
        s=random.normalvariate(randomlist[personind+4],randomlist[person+1])
        list1.append (s)
    for t in range(1,11):
        s=random.normalvariate(randomlist[personind+4], randomlist[personind+1])
        list2.append (s)
    for l in range (1,11):
        poang=xypoang(list1[l-1], list2[l-1])
        list3.append (poang)
    print(randomlist[personind], end="\t")
    for r in range (1,11):
        print(list3[r-1], end="\t")
    print("\n")
def main():
        contestants = open("pdel.txt","r")
        contestantsfile = contestants.readlines()
        contestantslist=[]
        for element in contestantsfile: 
                contestantslist.append (element.strip())
        present(contestantslist)
        while True:
                seasons= input("Write number of competitions")
                try:
                        competnr = int(seasons)
                except ValueError:
                        print ("Valid number, please")
                        continue
                if competnr>0:
                        break
                else:
                        print ("valid number please")
        nr=1
        while competnr>0:
                print("tävling nr",nr)
                x=0
                while x<int(len(contestantslist)/5):
                        userwant(contestantslist,x)
                        x=x+1
                competnr=competnr-1
                nr=nr+1
main()
```

Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\(name)\Desktop\programmering\p-del\p-del6.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()

File "C:\Users\(name)\Desktop\programmering\p-del\p-del6.py", line 59, in main
    userwant(contestantslist,x)

File "C:\Users\(name)\Desktop\programmering\p-del\p-del6.py", line 24, in userwant
    s=random.normalvariate(randomlist[personind+4],randomlist[person+1])

File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 382, in normalvariate
return mu + z*sigma

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: You might want to sort out your indentation. If it isn't causing problems now then it certainly will in the future.

Comment: Which indentation are we talking about?

Comment: the fact that it is sometimes 8 spaces and sometimes 4.

Comment: Ah, yeah you are right, did not notice that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading a file into a list, and you then proceed to pass that list to the function `userwant()` where you then pass items of that list to `random.normalvariate()`.

The problem is that `random.normalvariate()` expects `float`s as parameters, but your list contains `str`ings. You need to convert them to `float`s first.

Ideally, that would be done when reading the file, assuming that each line contains one floating point number:

```
for element in contestantsfile: 
    contestantslist.append(float(element))
```

If that's not the case, you'll need to do the conversion here:

```
s = random.normalvariate(float(randomlist[personind+4]),float(randomlist[person+1]))
```